# Where can I download the latest ngen.exe?

Tags: .net, ngen

I am using ngen.exe (the .Net Native Image Generator) version 2.0.50727.312. Is this the latest version? If not, where can I download the latest version? This [**page**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) on msdn does not appear to have a link to a download. If it matters, I need ngen.exe for .Net Framework 3.5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The .NET Runtime itself has been upgraded with what amounts to a "service pack" in the 3.5 version.  If you have .NET 3.5 installed on that box, you are running the latest version of NGEN, even if the version number is 2.0.50727.  Check out this article for more details:

http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2007/06/net-framework-35.html

Answer (score 5):

ngen.exe is stored in framework installation path

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
or
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(VS.80).aspx